# Connection status is "unknown" for AppService between UWP and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a uwp app which uses an app service to communicate to the wpf app using desktop bridge. The app service works completely fine in my machine. But in some of the machines I am facing the following issue.
When I try to launch the wpf app using `await Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();`
it launches successfully, but the connection status for `connection.OpenAsync()` is returned as `AppServiceConnectionStatus.Unknown`. I tried to find the reason for this but I didn't find anything. May I know what are the things which possibly cause the connection to fail? and what is the reason for this "unknown" status?

Also I just wanted to know what is the protocol used in app service to communicate between apps?

Sample Code in the wpf app:

```
        private static async void ThreadProc()
        {
            connection = new AppServiceConnection();
            connection.AppServiceName = "CommunicationService";
            connection.PackageFamilyName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
            connection.RequestReceived += Connection_RequestReceived;

            AppServiceConnectionStatus status = await connection.OpenAsync();   //status is "unknown"

        }
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Are you running the app as an administrator or using some other kind of user account compared to the machine on which it works?

Comment: `AppServiceConnectionStatus.Unknown` means `An unknown error occurred`. So there should be an error when you are trying to create an AppServiceConnection. Same as @mm8, I'd also want to know if the app is running as administrator because app service connections are not supported in elevated processes.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for your reply. I'm not running the app as administrator. Also the user accounts are of same kind in both the machines.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT  Is there any other parameters that I could check between the machines for this issue?

Comment: No, currently there are no parameters that could check the issue excepted `AppServiceConnectionStatus`. Maybe you need to try re-connect the AppService Connection when the status is Unknown.

Comment: If AppServices will not work, you can try my library for ipc between UWP and .Net Framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CorpusCallosum/ It does not require elevation, but does not support .Net Core and .Net 5 at non-UWP side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue might be related to anti-virus protection. Not sure what is blocked from the anti-virus protection that leads to the failure of the app services connection. If someone is facing this issue, please check the anti-virus protection first.